# C# - Serialize multiple objects of the same class

Tags: c#, serialization, syntax

I am working on a small utility to manage a few computers connected on a network. This utility will have a button "Add Computer" on the UI which allows the user to configure a new computer.

I have a class called component:

```
public class component
{

public string name { get; set; }
public string ip { get; set; }
public string room { get; set; }

bla bla


}
```

Please keep I am absolutely not a professional, so forgive me if the question sounds stupid.

The first problem I got is: How can I create multiple instances of the same class at runtime? What I figured out is using a deep clone, with serialiazation and deserialization. Is it a good approach?

Second problem. Let's say at runtime I managed to create my clones and I have an object for every computer in my network. How can I create a file containing all those objects? How can I serialize them?

I am not looking for code, but just for someone pointing me in the right direction, as I am pretty sure my approach is not exactly the best. All suggestions are welcome.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Any particular reason you are using DeepClone over, say, just creating multiple instances?

Comment: Also, possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15247053/serialize-multiple-objects

Comment: I think you should focus on more basic things like "how to make multiple instances of" than serializing. Pick up a tutorial on C# and do some basic assignments.

Comment: @kuhaku Dear kuhaku, I totally agree with you that what I am trying to achieve is far beyond my knowledge. However, that's the problem I am facing right now and I just would like some good advice on what to look into (a keyword, an article, a book even). I didn't ask anyone to do my homework - in fact I didn't post any code). Thanks for your help.

Comment: No need for a book, just google every question you have or anything you don't understand from the answers you got. If you find yourself struggling even with that, then I suggest to start from the basics, i.e. google "learn C#" and go through the steps.

Comment: Lists are serialize-able if your class(es) is/are serialize-able. [This resource](https://www.dotnetperls.com/serialize-list) provides some runnable examples on serializing lists.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, howto create instance of my class

```
var myInstance = new MyClass();
```

Howto serialize instance of MyClass to file

```
    var instance= new MyClass(); // <- instance
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter("Path_to_file"))
    {
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
        ser.Serialize(sw, instance);
    }
```

Howto read instance of MyClass from file

```
    using (var sr = new StreamReader("path_To_file"))
    {
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
        var myInstance = ser.Deserialize(sr) as T; // <- instance
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To store inside your program  multiple instances of the same class you need an object called List ([here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) the MSDN reference and [here](https://www.dotnetperls.com/list) a fast tutorial). 
To store the List you have multiple choice: serialize and deserialize using [xml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx), [json](http://json.net), [protobuf protocol](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net) and much more, it's you choice.